# Rails new install--alarmingly many "Bundler cannot continue" dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I installed Rails anew (I think from a gem) and created my new app, but running bundler failed. Then, and since then, it's hit probably 20 dependencies of the form:

`` Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/turbo
links-2.5.3.gem)
An error occurred while installing turbolinks (2.5.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install turbolinks -v '2.5.3'` succeeds before bundling. ``

with different gems needing to be installed. It's no big problem to run `gem install <gemname> -v'<version>' --no-rdoc --no-ri` but it's worrying me that something has not worked correctly in the big picture. My scant understanding of bundler is that it's supposed to avoid dependency hell, but instead the opposite seems to be happening. Should I be worried? Should I have searched for a one-click Rails installer instead?

NOTE: I thought the following was also a problem:

`Fetching: turbolinks-2.5.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing turbolinks:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.`

because Rails should only require Ruby 1.9.3 or newer, which I have. But it turned out that after the seemingly failed installation of turbolinks, I could still run `bundle install` and get past that point, even though this seems a bit dodgy. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run

```
gem update --system
```

Or

In your Gemfile or wherever you have specified the gems list and replace source `https://......` with this source `http://.......` , something like

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with librarian-puppet.

If you install active-support first it works.

I don't know why this solved the problem.